# How I change name below app name after publish app on google play store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

How I change name below app name after publish app on google play store. This may organization name or domain name. but I do not write any thing during making flutter project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ7u0.png)

I try a lot to change this but fail. Can you know its solution

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic -- but that is not part of your project. You filled that into the Play Console.

Comment: In the left side menu of play console go to developer page and update developer name.

Comment: ideally you cannot do that.